# XML in the csproj file

Tags: c#, csproj

Can anyone point me to a schema or a list of properties valid inside the C# csproj file?  I've looked, but don't appear to be able to find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You mean something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx) documentation?
A reference can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx)

Comment: Thankyou, but I was after more of a reference than a walk-through.  I've come across a property that doesn't appear to be available from the IDE and was wondering what else is available.

Comment: I'm not sure that i understand you, but i have edited my post to provide a link to a MSBuild project file schema reference. Maybe it will be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980793/where-can-i-find-the-schema-xsd-for-a-csproj-file)...

Csproj are actually MSBuild files and I think the reference can be found here:

[MSBuild Project File Schema Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx)

The schema used by VS (VS 2008) is located here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Xml\Schemas\1033\MSBuild\Microsoft.Build.Core.xsd