# How else can I create a folder in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Something has happened to me and now Visual Studio 2013 freezes on right click on a folder. Is there a way to create a folder besides doing it from the context menu?

Comment: Is this happening in specific situations (does this happen when running Visual Studio as Administrator?), or a certain condition? Do you have full read/write access to the project's root?

Comment: You should probably uninstall any (new first) extensions you've installed and if none of those work do a repair install on visual studio. You can drag / drop existing folders from explorer into visual studio as well but you should fix the source of the problem

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can create folders in the file system using your favorite file manager and folders which you see in your Visual Studio are either just xml one-liners in `*.*proj` file

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Folder Include="path\to\folder\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

or visual helpers derived automatically from the structure of the other [group items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646dk05y.aspx).

See also:

- [What is the purpose of <Folder/> items in the csproj files?](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/10191/28242.aspx)
- [XML in the csproj file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631819/xml-in-the-csproj-file)